# Continuous for each variables does not implies continuous

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Prove or disprove the following statement:

**Statement.** *Continuous for each variables, when other variables are fixed, implies continuous?* More clearly, prove or disprove the following problem:

Let $\displaystyle f:\left[ a,b \right]\times \left[ c,d \right]\to \mathbb{R}$ for which:

- For every $\displaystyle {{x}_{0}}\in \left[ a,b \right]$, $\displaystyle f\left( {{x}_{0}},y \right)$ is continuous on $\displaystyle \left[ c,d \right]$ respect to variable $ \displaystyle y$.
- For every $ \displaystyle {{y}_{0}}\in \left[ c,d \right]$, $ \displaystyle f\left( x,{{y}_{0}} \right)$ is continuous on $ \displaystyle \left[ a,b \right]$ respect to variable $\displaystyle x$.

Then $\displaystyle f\left( x,y \right)$ is continuous on $ \displaystyle \left[ a,b \right]\times \left[ c,d \right]$. ?

https://hongnguyenquanba.wordpress.com/2016/05/12/problem-6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},&(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
0,&(x,y)=(0,0)\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: It's classical, right? I don't think about this function.

Comment: @QuảnBáHồngNguyễn: Yes, it's a rather well-known counterexample. You should remember it, because it is useful for such problems.

Comment: OK. Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Standard example:
$$ f(x,y) = \dfrac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$$
with $f(0,0) = 0$.

Comment: I also want to build some function is discontinuous at the origin. I don't think a simple counter-example like this. It's classical, right?

Comment: This is discontinuous at the origin.  To see this, note e.g. that $f(x,x) = 1/2$ for $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @QuảnBáHồngNguyễn: Note that $f$ is constant along radial approach to the origin

Answer (score 0):

I have built a counter-example for this statement. Because the building process is quite complicated (it has images too). So I post my *counter example* in the following link:
https://hongnguyenquanba.wordpress.com/2016/05/12/problem-6/